# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE while inserting from pyspark dataframe to an external database table via JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Well, I'm using PySpark and I have a Spark dataframe using which I insert the data into a mysql table.

`url = "jdbc:mysql://hostname/myDB?user=xyz&password=pwd"`

`df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="myTable", mode="append")`

I want to update a column value (which is not in primary key) by the sum of its column value and a specific number.

I've tried with different modes (append, overwrite) DataFrameWriter.jdbc() function.

My question is how do we update a column value as in we do it with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in mysql, while inserting the pyspark dataframe data into a table.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in vanilla `pyspark` (or Scala Spark, for that matter), as you only have 4 write modes (source https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc):

> append: Append contents of this DataFrame to existing data.
>
> overwrite: Overwrite existing data.
>
> ignore: Silently ignore this operation if data already exists.
>
> error or errorifexists (default case): Throw an exception if data already exists.

There is, however, a couple of hacky workarounds:

1. There's a `jython` package that allows you to write `jdbc` queries directly, therefore you can structure your code to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. Here's the link: https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/
2. If you're competent in Scala, you can write a new mode or overwrite the `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc` and the `JdbcUtils.scala INSERT INTO` to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. Or even better, using a `MERGE` statement such as:

```
MERGE INTO table-name
USING table-ref
AS name
ON cond
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
```

Depending on your flavour of SQL.

3. Use a *staging table* where you overwrite, then write a simple `mysql` trigger on this staging environment in such a way that it runs `INSERT INTO target_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.
4. Move your Spark DataFrame to `pandas` DataFrame and write your `upsert` query there using `sqlalchemy` and raw queries.
5. Create a pipeline using *Spark Streaming* backed by Apache Kafka, then use a tool with jdbc upsert functionality such as *Kafka Connect* to `upsert` directly into your target table. Or use Kafka Connect for `upserting` from staging table to target table. Here's some reading https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html#idempotent-writes

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to insert the data into a staging table, and then migrate it into the final tables using a SQL statement executed by the driver program. Than you can use any valid SQL syntax relevant to your database provider.